# WooCommerce при обновлении корзины - пустая страница

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, обновление, корзина, cart

Прошу помощи.

Сама проблема: при нажатии на кнопке "Обновить корзину" получаю пустую страницу, то есть сама корзина не отображается. При повторном обновлении страницы все вижу как и должно быть. 
[Сам сайт](http://%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2.%D1%80%D1%84/oborudovanie/)

То есть любые манипуляции на странице корзины приводят к тому, что сама страница корзины пропадает, но при обновлении страницы корзина появляется и видно результат действий. Страница корзины создана [woocommerce_cart].
Пробовал из разных браузеров. Читаю интернет и форумы уже неделю, но ничего по своей теме не нахожу. Плагины кэширования отключал проблема сохранилась.
Дебаг включал, ошибок при выполнении этих действий нет. Только warning и notice.

Галочка "Включить Ajax для кнопки добавления в корзину в архивах" установлена

Дополнил снимком экрана. То есть получается что текст который написан после короткого кода корзины появляется всегда, а именно корзина на загружается.
[image: Содержимое страницы корзины]

Файл cart.min.js последней версии.

Покопался еще и вот что у меня получается.
При выполнении вот этого кода

```js
// Make call to actual form post URL.
$.ajax({
  type: $form.attr('method'),
  url: $form.attr('action'),
  data: $form.serialize(),
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    console.info("response " + response);
    update_wc_div(response);
  },
  //     error: function() {
  //        alert('Load was failed.');
  //         console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! error', arguments);
  //      },

  complete: function() {
    unblock($form);
    unblock($('div.cart_totals'));
    $.scroll_to_notices($('[role="alert"]'));
  }
});
},
```

Я в ответе получаю вот такую страницу

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8" lang="ru-RU">
 <![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru-RU">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Войти &lsaquo; Шинков.рф | Шиномонтаж круглосуточно 24 на 7 &#8212; WordPress</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .login h1 a {
      background: transparent url("http://шинков.рф/wp-content/themes/shinkov/images/logo.png") center no-repeat!important;
      width: 250px!important;
      height: 65px!important;
      outline: none!important;
    }
  </style>
  <!--n2css-->
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css' href='http://шинков.рф/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='buttons-css' href='http://шинков.рф/wp-includes/css/buttons.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='forms-css' href='http://шинков.рф/wp-admin/css/forms.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='l10n-css' href='http://шинков.рф/wp-admin/css/l10n.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='login-css' href='http://шинков.рф/wp-admin/css/login.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/1B74BD89-2A22-4B93-B451-1C9E1052A0EC/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>

<body class="login login-action-login wp-core-ui  locale-ru-ru">
  <div id="login">
    <h1><a href="http://шинков.рф/" title="Сайт работает на WordPress" tabindex="-1">Сайт работает на WordPress</a></h1>

    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://шинков.рф/wp-login.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <label for="user_login">Имя пользователя или e-mail<br />
  <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Пароль<br />
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
      </p>
      <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  /> Запомнить меня</label></p>
      <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Войти" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://xn--b1alglg0d.xn--p1ai/wp-admin/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
      </p>
    </form>

    <p id="nav">
      <a href="http://шинков.рф/account/lost-password/">Забыли пароль?</a>
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function wp_attempt_focus() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          try {
            d = document.getElementById('user_login');
            d.focus();
            d.select();
          } catch (e) {}
        }, 200);
      }

      wp_attempt_focus();
      if (typeof wpOnload == 'function') wpOnload();
    </script>

    <p id="backtoblog"><a href="http://шинков.рф/">&larr; Назад к сайту &laquo;Шинков.рф | Шиномонтаж круглосуточно 24 на 7&raquo;</a></p>
    <div class="privacy-policy-page-link"><a class="privacy-policy-link" href="http://шинков.рф/privacy_policy/">Политика конфиденциальности</a></div>
  </div>


  <div class="clear"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

То есть сервер просит авторизации. Почему так?

Comment: Получается, что если я разрываю связь WooCommerce со страницей, то есть удаляю сопоставление страницы корзины в настройках плагина, не знаю как объяснить… То получается, что в этот момент обновление корзины идет нормально, при нахождение по адресу /cart, то есть текущая страница корзины. При этом перехода на корзину нет, получается 404 и редирект на главную. Так как связь разорвана. Но вот при таком раскладе кнопка отрабатывает правильно. Как только я показываю плагину какая страница является корзиной:все — ошибка. Не хватает у меня знаний понять в чем проблема…

Comment: Аналогичная проблема. Вам удалось решить?
wp 5.1.1
woocommerce 3.5.5 в песочнице, все о

Comment: Столкнулся а аналогичной проблемой. Удалось ли как-то решить?