# Ajax передача формы, как это должно работать и аутентификация

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Исходные данные:
[Сайт](http://xn--b1alglg0d.xn--p1ai/cart/) на WordPress с Woocommerce.
Тема самописная. Интеграция магазина была сделана недавно.

### Проблема:

Изменяем количество товара для заказа. При нажатии на кнопку обновить корзину сам код корзины на странице исчезает и появляется после обновления страницы, мой же [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/838350/woocommerce-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) для пояснения.
Есть две процедуры которые обрабатывают данное действие.

### Процедура первая

```js
quantity_update: function($form) {
  block($form);
  block($('div.cart_totals'));

  // Provide the submit button value because wc-form-handler expects it.
  $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
    .attr('name', 'update_cart')
    .attr('value', 'Update Cart')
    .appendTo($form);

  var datastring = $form.serialize();
  // Make call to actual form post URL.
  $.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    //data:     $form.serialize(),
    data: datastring,

    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {
      update_wc_div(response);
    },
    complete: function() {
      unblock($form);
      unblock($('div.cart_totals'));
      $.scroll_to_notices($('[role="alert"]'));
    }
  });
}
```

### Процедура вторая. Фрагмент

```js
var update_wc_div = function(html_str, preserve_notices) {
  /*  console.info(" " + );*/
  console.info("html_str " + html_str);
  var $html = $.parseHTML(html_str);
  console.info("$html " + $html);
  var $new_form = $('.woocommerce-cart-form', $html);
  console.info("$new_form " + $new_form);
  var $new_totals = $('.cart_totals', $html);
  var $notices = $('.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-info', $html);

  // No form, cannot do this.
  if ($('.woocommerce-cart-form').length === 0) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
    return;
  }
}
```

---

На шаге

```js
var $new_form = $( '.woocommerce-cart-form', $html );
```

Переменная `$new_form` так и остается неопределенной и соответственно дальше по коду понятно почему не появляется вставка корзины.

### Пояснение

**Все процедуры которые используются - это процедуры из коробки плагина WooCommerce. Последняя версия плагина. Я только добавил свои вставки для отладки**

### Вопросы:

1. Если делать обновление кол-во товаров без авторизации на сервере, то в параметре **response** функции *update_wc_div( response );* получаем страницу аутентификации на сервере. Почему так происходит?
2. Если все эти манипуляции производить под администратором WordPress, то получаю страницу в которой нет класса **woocommerce-cart-form** и соответственно код дальше не работает. Хотя на самой странице при ее сериализации он присутствует. То есть получается аякс запрос не возвращает в html этих данных.

Если написал что-то не правильно - не судите строго - поправлю. Третья неделя пошла, проблему не могу решить. Перечитал все похожее в инете. Хоть направление подскажите. Не знаю с какой стороны подойти к проблеме.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78802/discussion-on-question-by--ajax------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общение с автором вопроса было длительным. После удаления всех плагинов, кроме WC, смены темы, ничего добиться не удалось.

Перенесли сайт с помощью Duplicator на другой сервер - проблема исчезла.

Перенесли с помощью Duplicator обратно - сайт заработал как положено и на прежнем месте.

### Вывод

Скорее всего, проблемы была изначально вызвана неправильным (без duplicator) переноса сайта. Или тем, что автор вопроса правил базу вручную (выяснилось в ходе общения).

О том, какие проблемы может вызвать неправильный перенос сайта, и как делать перенос правильно, можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562).